# Docker Build Problem "Error: Cannot find module"

Tags: docker, vue.js, dockerfile, nuxt.js, node-modules

I have a problem with the execution of the `docker build` command, in my Nuxt frontend docker container. This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as base

RUN npm install -g pnpm

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./

RUN pnpm install

COPY . .

RUN pnpm run build
EXPOSE 3000

FROM node:lts-alpine as final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=base /usr/src/app/.output .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "server/index.mjs"]
```

When running `docker build` with this `Dockerfile` I get the following error:

```
 => [base 4/7] COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./                                                                 0.1s
 => [base 5/7] RUN pnpm install                                                                                   13.0s
 => [base 6/7] COPY . .                                                                                            2.7s
 => ERROR [base 7/7] RUN pnpm run build                                                                            0.7s
------
 > [base 7/7] RUN pnpm run build:
0.581
0.581 > @ build /usr/src/app
0.581 > nuxi build
0.581
0.602 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
0.602   throw err;
0.602   ^
0.602
0.602 Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.mjs'
0.602     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
0.602     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
0.602     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
0.602     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
0.602   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
0.602   requireStack: []
0.602 }
0.602
0.602 Node.js v20.11.1
0.605  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
------
Dockerfile:24
--------------------
  22 |     COPY . .
  23 |
  24 | >>> RUN pnpm run build
  25 |     EXPOSE 3000
  26 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pnpm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

1. I ran `docker build` with the `--no-cache` flag.
2. I commented out the `RUN pnpm run build` line and went inside the container to check if the file exists in there. It does not.

Should this file even be in there? Has anybody had the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I was missing the .dockerignore file, so my node_modules folder was copied over.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all of the required packages listed in `package.json`?

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxi build"
  },
  "engines": {
    "npm": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nuxt": "3.11.1",
    "nuxi": "3.11.1",
    "@nuxt/kit": "3.11.1"
  }
}
```

`Dockerfile` (Same as the one provided in question except the `EXPOSE` omitted from `base` stage.)

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as base

RUN npm install -g pnpm

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./

RUN pnpm install

COPY . .

RUN pnpm run build

FROM node:lts-alpine as final

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=base /usr/src/app/.output .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "server/index.mjs"]
```

[image]